# Installing web2py on Solaris 10 : "ImportError: No module named _md5"

Tags: python, compiler-errors, solaris, web2py, python-2.6

I'm using python 2.6.2 on solaris 10 on a sparc.

And this is the only python version.

$PATH is pretty clean : /usr/bin::/usr/local/bin:/var/opt/python2.6.2/usr/local/bin

Any ideas ?

Edit : Just Found this link which talks about resolving the issue on Linux :  http://johnsofteng.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/python-importerror-no-module-named-_md5/

Those binaries aren't available on Solaris, but something similar should be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the OpenSSL development files and rebuild Python.

Comment: Thanks !! o.k.. I installed python from opensolaris.com to avoid compilation of python.. but it seems I'll have to do it. Let me google how to do that. Thanks again Ignacio.

Comment: Should installing openssl package and adding the lib directory to the PATH work ?

Comment: I'm not certain. That error message isn't the normal one shown when a shared object isn't available.

Comment: Solved !!! Installed openssl-1.0.0d from sunfreeware.com and then set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the libs. However to avoid future issues I'm trying to compile python on Solaris 10. Thanks Ignacio, your openssl tip really helped.